# Singleton - Spring Bean why not thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, thread-safety, spring-bean

I understand `Object Creation` and `Thread safety` are two different things.

`Singleton` is a way of constructing an object, some design pattern we follow to construct the object.

Spring Bean - Using `Singleton` scope, we guarantee that only 1 instance will be there, but still Spring bean is not thread safe.. why..??

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be thread safe, precisely because just one instance is created, so every request(thread) will use the very same instance, so concurrency issues may happens.

If for example your scope is prototype, Spring wont use singleton and then it will create an instance per getClass invokation.

Same thing for request or session, instance will be created by request or per user session.

As a rule, use the prototype scope for all state-full beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.

you can read in the documentation how it´s working

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm